# Prove that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty, y \rightarrow \infty} F_{XY}(x, y) = 1. $

Tags: probability, probability-theory, solution-verification

> *Prove that* $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty, y \rightarrow \infty} F_{XY}(x, y) = 1. $

**Attempt:**

$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty, y \rightarrow \infty} F_{XY}(x, y) = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty, y \rightarrow \infty} P(X \leq x, Y \leq y) = P(X \leq \infty, Y \leq \infty) = P(\{R_X\}\cap\{R_Y\}) = P(R_{XY}) = 1. $

Where $R_X$ denotes the range of $X$, $R_Y$ denotes the range of $Y$, and $R_{XY}$ denotes the range of the bivariate r.v. $(X, Y)$.

**Official proof:**

Since $\{X \leq \infty, Y \leq \infty\} = S$, we have

$$ P(\{X \leq \infty, Y \leq \infty\}) = F_{XY}(\infty, \infty) = P(S) = 1. $$

I want to know if my proof is valid. I think so because, well, suppose it's a univariate problem, then $P(R_X) = P(S) = 1.$ But in the bivariate case, I'm unsure if $R_X \cap R_Y = R_{XY}$. Looks like a Lemma I'd have to prove separately. But I like my proof better than just saying that $\{X \leq \infty, Y \leq \infty\} = S$, because this last equation isn't very clear in my head.

**Edit:**

Okay, I have already found a counter example to $R_X \cap R_Y = R_{XY}$.

So suppose my attempt is, then

$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty, y \rightarrow \infty} F_{XY}(x, y) = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty, y \rightarrow \infty} P(X \leq x, Y \leq y) = P(X \leq \infty, Y \leq \infty) = P(R_{XY}) = 1. $

Comment: Okay, I have already found a counter example to $R_X \cap R_Y = R_{XY}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any sequence $(x_n,y_n)\nearrow(\infty,\infty)$. Then
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}F_{X,Y}(x_n,y_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathsf{P}(X\le x_n,Y\le y_n)=\mathsf{P}\!\left(\bigcup_{n\ge 1}\{X\le x_n,Y\le y_n\}\right)=1.
$$

Comment: Very clear proof, thank you. I was wondering, though, if my proof is correct (the last line of the OP). Could you please verify?

Comment: You need to use sequences to justify the second equality (continuity of $P$ from below).

Comment: Also $R_{XY}$ is typically $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that
$$
\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{R}^2) = 1 = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} dF_{X,Y}(x,y) 
$$
where 
$$
\lim_{(x,y) \to (\infty, \infty) } F_{X,Y}(x,y) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} dF_{X,Y}(x,y) = \int \int f_{X,Y}(x,y) dx dy  = 1
$$

Comment: Hmmm, looks good, but it supposes $(X, Y)$ is a continuous bivariate r.v.

Comment: I believe that Lebesgue dominated measure will solve this problem (i.e., the integral may refer to a countable sum as well)

Comment: Well, I'm not familiarized with Lebesgue Integration so I couldn't use that, besides, using Lebesgue integrals on this problem feels like "nuking a bug".